# "Could not resolve host: github.com" error while updating Homebrew after installing git

Tags: macos, osx-lion, git, homebrew

I'm using OS X Lion (10.7.2).

I installed Homebrew on my Mac, and I executed the command below.

```
$ brew install git
```

and then:

```
$ brew update
error: Could not resolve host: github.com; nodename nor servname provided, or not known while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git/info/refs   
fatal: HTTP request failed
Error: Failed while executing git pull  origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

What happened there?

Comment: this question belongs to [su]. check your network and that you can reach github.com with your browser

Comment: what does the command `ping github.com` return?

Comment: Mac OS X already has git - just install the developer tools (Xcode) if  you haven't already.

Comment: @PaulR Maybe they want a more recent version?

Comment: @slhck: could be - the question isn't very clear as to motivation

Answer (score -1):

1) If you use CLI package managers such as brew, port, fink, … **some installations require root privileges**. In **these cases** run your installation command with **sudo**:

```
sudo brew install git
```

2) Check wether you can github.com via a web browser.

Comment: Actually, you're not supposed to use sudo with Homebrew. [Installation  instructions](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation) say so, as does [the FAQ](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: It's **wrong** to say that installation in Homebrew is "properly" done with elevated privileges. Please fix your answer.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I don't know `brew` in particular, just CLI package managers in general, and from my experience I can say that some installations require root privileges, for this cases executing via `sudo` can help.